# Unable to update fields to null value using action in Dynamics CRM customization

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization

We have an action to update certain entities in our system where we have to pass a null value to the following data types:

Decimal

Single Line Text

Multi Line Text

We are using a late bound with Post Operation Synchronous action running on server. We use Dynamics 365 online version (Server version: 9.1.0000.10951, Client version: 1.3.2539-191119-175232). We can update value to any non-empty value without any issue.We need to remove the value of those fields. When we set null the value doesn't change and remains the old value. We used `string.empty` and `null` for SLT and MLT and empty for decimal.

We are also using CRM dll version 9.0.7 and we have updated it to the latest version as well but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about clearing the value in Plugin code on custom Action message or UI WF 'clear' like discussed here - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/208980/on-demand-workflow-to-clear-select-field-values-in-dynamics-crm-form

Answer (score 0):

If you use Post Operation stage, you should call Update() method after value assignation.
It would work for any type of field.

```
entity["fieldname"] = null;
service.Update(entity);
```